# Frazer + Wordpress Integration

Tags: wordpress, plugins, wordpress-rest-api

I am looking for any possible way to integrate Frazer (used car inventory software) to integrate with WordPress? Is there any possible way or do I have to create Custom API?

Comment: Can you share what you tried before that?

Comment: Hi Rajeev. I only used different theme because there is no way to integrate frazer.

Comment: Hi, I think Frazer provided documentation, If yes you should follow this step by step

Answer (score 0):

For Wordpress there are ready-made plugins integration with Frazer. If you do not have specific requirements, it is easier to buy a ready-made car  template with built-in integration on Themeforest.

For example, this template has a ready-made integration
https://themeforest.net/item/automotive-car-dealership-business-wordpress-theme/9210971

Comment: I have tried this and this theme doesn't support frazer integration it has some kind of built in inventory management plugin nothing else. I want to integrate frazer so I can pull data from there.